# iOS toolbar not showing navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am having trouble getting the toolbar of my navigation controller to show. When I do

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

within the init method of mainController the toolbar does not show. However, when I use that line in the commented part below, it works fine. I realize it isn't working because I create mainController before I create the navigation controller. Is there a way to fix this so that I can call that line in the init method of mainController?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

  rootController = [[mainController alloc] init];
  UINavigationController *navController =
      [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
  //turn on toolbar

  _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  _window.rootViewController = navController;
  [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the requirement to do it in init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in the `viewDidLoad` method of your `UIViewController`. In your `init` method `self.navigationController` is probably `nil`

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController is going to be nil during init because the controller hasn't been pushed on the navigation controller stack yet. In order to access it during init you will either have to

1) pass it as a parameter to a custom init method

2) set it as a property on the application delegate and then access it in the init method through [UIApplication sharedApplication]